# Do group policy Startup scripts run for people who launch VPN?

Tags: group-policy

We had to create a batch file to run when a user first logs into their PC.  I put an entry in group policy as such:

1. Log into domain controller and fired off group policy
2. Open Group Policy Management
3. Expand the Domains and open the OU that I need to modify
4. Here you will find the item Logon Script - MyCompanyName
5. Right click on it and select Edit
6. Expand User Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Scripts
7. There should be a Logon script - you will see the call to the .bat file here (this calls the exe file)

This now seems to work for anyone in our actual building and logging into our network.  I tested with a few people.  However, we have a lot of people who are not in the building who log into their work PC and then manually run Watchguard VPN to get onto the network.  I thought group policy stuff runs even if you VPN in?  But apparently that is not happening?  I also did a `gpupdate /force` and a `gpupdate /sync` and it says it is up to date but I know the batch / executable was not run when they log in because we have a mechanism that logs if it runs and that shows nothing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logon scripts run when a user logs onto the computer. If the computer is not connected to the VPN, and therefore not connected to your corporate network when the user logs onto the computer, then the logon script is not going to run when the user logs onto the computer. You can look into using a VPN client that connects prior to the user logging on (although I don't think the WG VPN client has this option), or find another method for performing whatever actions the logon script performs, such as putting a copy of the logon script on the desktop of the users and informing then to run the logon script after they connect to the VPN.

Startup scripts are for computers. They run when the computer starts up, so long as the computer is connected to the corporate network.

Logon scripts are for users. They run when the user logs on, so long as the computer is connected to the corporate network.

Comment: Ok Thank you - I understand completly.